# Deriving the equation for confinement kinetic energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

So confinement kinetic energy is given by $\frac{\hbar}{2m\triangle x^2}$. I'm a little confused with regards to how that it arrived at:

I started with the Uncertainty Principle : $\triangle p = \frac{\hbar}{\triangle x}$ (just ignoring the ≥ for now, and using an equals sign).

Now, kinetic energy =$ \frac{p^2}{2m}$. I can see that substituting in the above expression for $\triangle p $ into the bottom equation for p would give that equation for confinement kinetic energy - but how can we just say that $\triangle p $ is the same as p?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

- By using the equal sign in $\Delta p = \hbar/\Delta x$, we get the minimal uncertainty in the momentum. This is what we are interested in, because this the the physical lower bound. An upper bound does not exists.
- Now the question is, what is the kin. energy associated with this uncertainty in momentum? So let's consider a state with expectation value $p_0$ of the momentum. The expectation value of it's kin. energy is $$E[\frac{(p_0 + \Delta p)^2}{2m}] = E[\frac{p_0^2}{2m}] + E[\frac{p_0 \cdot \Delta p}{m}] + E[\frac{(\Delta p)^2}{2m}] = \frac{p_0^2}{2m} + \frac{p_0 \cdot E[\Delta p]}{m} + \frac{E[(\Delta p)^2]}{2m}$$ The first term is the standard kin. energy of the momentum state $p_0$. The mid-term vanishes, if we assume a *symmetric distribution* of the uncertainty in $p_0$. The last term is what you are looking for. It does not vanish, because $(\Delta p)^2 \ge 0$.

PS: I guess there is a $\hbar$ missing in your first expression.